# Algorithm: Maximum number I can achieve

Tags: c++, algorithm, knapsack-problem

I got set of numbers in an array. (Max is 110 set of numbers)

For example I have 3 numbers in an array:

`5.0 , 90.0, 8.5`

I have another number. Lets say `98.6` in this example.

How can I determine the maximum numbers I can add which the sum is lower than that single number (98.6)?

In this example we can choose 90.0 and 8.5 which is lower than 98.6.

Comment: This question is far too broad. The knapsack-problem is a very well known, well documented problem with numerous algorithms and solutions online. You have shown no attempt at researching any algorithm, and have not posted any attempt at code. This is not a code writing service, please make an attempt yourself and come back if you get stuck.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

"How can I determine the maximum numbers I can add which the sum is lower than that single number "

It's very simple , just sort the array ( maybe using merge-sort ), contiguously add numbers from beginning till sum is less than given number.

EDITED AS QUESTION IS TOO BROAD:-

Solution suggested above is valid if you just want maximum numbers fall in your bracket without caring for how close sum is to given number. If you care for latter then google "knapsack-problem".

Comment: That wont work. In the above example (5.0, 8.5 , 90) if we sum 5.0 + 8.5 + 90, the answer will be 103.5 which is wrong. It should be lower than 98.6. (Also 8.5 + 5.0 is not correct answer too)

Comment: This idea will not work. Say I want to stay under `50`, and I have elements `48 ..., 2, 1`. That algorithm will add `48`, then stop, even though it should also gather the `1` element. The same problem arises if the list is sorted in ascending order.

Comment: @Cyber So, if limit is 50, then first you sort the array 1,2,.... 48. It will sum up all small numbers till sum is less than 50. I didn't get what you are saying

Comment: @ravi The knapsack problem is an optimization problem that basically says "with the given items, how close can I get to this limit without exceeding it?". In that case, if your limit is `50` finding a solution for `48` is insufficient if there is a possible arrangement to get `49`, which your solution will not find. In the case of `1+2+3+...` it will terminate at `9` with a total sum of `44` which certainly isn't optimal.

Comment: @Cyber He didn't mention that condition ( he wants maximum sum )He just said he want maximum numbers.

Comment: @ravi I know. That's what I'm trying to explain to you. If you simply add a sorted list from either end, in 99% of the cases you will not get the maximum sum. There is some subset of numbers, in no particular order, that will get you the maximum sum.

Comment: @Cyber Yes agree completely.